# Copy certain values from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am implementing a dictionary data structure to store per day results of a climate model. For stability reasons first and last 5 days are left out. I need to plot those values. Is there any effective way to do this?

The data is of the form:

```
dict = {
    'day1': 200435,
    'day2': 23354235,
    ...,
    'day30': 32435
}
plt(dict.keys(), dict.values())
```

Comment: Will 26-30 always be the last 5 days?

Comment: Do you mean Graph-Plot ??

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the body of the question - could you read [ask] and clarify what you are actually asking?

Comment: Do you know you will get an arbitrary order for the keys and values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do both filtering and plotting of your data.

```
data = {'day1':200435,'day2':23354235}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 'index').sort_index()

# Plot selected days
df['day5':'day25'].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
dict_keys = list(set(dict.keys()) - set(['day26','day27','day28','day29','day30']))

data = [dict[i] for i in dict_keys]
```

`data` now contains 25 days of data which you can use to plot a graph.